# How to apply ng-class (css property) upon click of radio button?

Tags: css, angularjs

I am very new to this so apologies if this may seem like a too-easy question! I want to change the background color of the two divs (boxes) corresponding to the color of the radio button. So the pink radio button would make the divs pink, red would make them red, and so on. Eventually I would also like the body bg-color and text color to change - but one step at a time. Is the ng-value on the input type correct? I know the ng-class on the divs is definitely not... but I am not sure what it needs to be?

Thanks a ton in advance!

```
 <body ng-app="MyModule">
    <div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
        <!-- Create input radio button -->
        <input type="radio" 
            name="color" 
            ng-model="ctrl.colorSelected" 
            ng-value="ctrl.bgColorRed">Red

        <input type="radio" 
            name="color" 
            ng-model="ctrl.colorSelected" 
            ng-value="ctrl.bgColorPink">Pink

       <input type="radio" 
            name="color" 
            ng-model="ctrl.colorSelected" 
            ng-value="ctrl.bgColorOrange">Orange

       <input type="radio" 
            name="color" 
            ng-model="ctrl.colorSelected" 
            ng-value="ctrl.bgColorYellow">Yellow

        <div class="box" ng-class="ctrl.bgColorRed">
        Letterpress craft beer typewriter, bitters butcher ennui heirloom   celiac. Four dollar toast pork belly 8-bit trust fund, raw denim letterpress shoreditch stumptown food truck locavore venmo typewriter blog. Post-ironic chambray lumbersexual, fashion axe hoodie kitsch swag yuccie organic. DIY hoodie lomo, austin post-ironic literally portland shoreditch pour-over neutra sriracha YOLO selvage thundercats messenger bag.
        </div>
    <div class="box" ng-class="">
        Tumblr hammock authentic, humblebrag pitchfork ramps listicle cliche distillery ethical 8-bit vice. 3 wolf moon whatever direct trade fanny pack franzen, swag polaroid austin letterpress. Street art health goth everyday carry heirloom hoodie echo park gluten-free irony, viral venmo brunch vegan pop-up. Man braid listicle food truck, fashion axe austin polaroid pop-up shoreditch post-ironic scenester jean shorts synth.
            </div>


     //////// JS /////////
        var myMod = angular.module("MyModule", []);
        myMod.controller("MyController", function() {
        var self = this;
        self.colorSelected = " ";
        self.bgColorRed=["red"];
        self.bgColorPink=["pink"];
        self.bgColorOrange=["orange"];
        self.bgColorYellow=["yellow"];
        self.textColor=["white", "strong"]; 

    });

    ///// CSS ///////////
    .box {
                width: 350px;
                height: 350px;
                background-color: grey;
                margin-top: 50px;
                margin-left: 100px;
                padding: 20px;
                float: left;
                text-align: justify;
            }
            .red {
                background-color: red;
            }
            .pink {
                background-color: pink;
            }
        .orange {
                background-color: orange;
            }
        .yellow {
          background-color: yellow;
        }
            .white {
                color: white;
            }
            .strong {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sash2507/w1waetd4/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code

```js
var myMod = angular.module("MyModule", []);
myMod.controller("MyController", function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.colorSelected = "";
  // Class change assignment
  vm.bgColorRed = "red";
  vm.bgColorPink = "pink";
  vm.bgColorOrange = "orange";
  vm.bgColorYellow = "yellow";
  vm.textColor = ["white", "strong"];



});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding: 25px;
  float: left;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 1.15em;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}
.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.white {
  color: white;
}
.strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="MyModule">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    <!-- Create input radio button -->
    <input type="radio" name="color" ng-model="ctrl.colorSelected" ng-value="ctrl.bgColorRed">Red

    <input type="radio" name="color" ng-model="ctrl.colorSelected" ng-value="ctrl.bgColorPink">Pink

    <input type="radio" name="color" ng-model="ctrl.colorSelected" ng-value="ctrl.bgColorOrange">Orange

    <input type="radio" name="color" ng-model="ctrl.colorSelected" ng-value="ctrl.bgColorYellow">Yellow

    <div class="box" ng-class="{red: ctrl.colorSelected == ctrl.bgColorRed, pink: ctrl.colorSelected == ctrl.bgColorPink, orange: ctrl.colorSelected == ctrl.bgColorOrange, yellow: ctrl.colorSelected == ctrl.bgColorYellow}">
      {{ctrl.colorSelected}} Letterpress craft beer typewriter, bitters butcher ennui heirloom celiac. Four dollar toast pork belly 8-bit trust fund, raw denim letterpress shoreditch stumptown food truck locavore venmo typewriter blog. Post-ironic chambray
      lumbersexual, fashion axe hoodie kitsch swag yuccie organic. DIY hoodie lomo, austin post-ironic literally portland shoreditch pour-over neutra sriracha YOLO selvage thundercats messenger bag.
    </div>
    <div class="box" ng-class="{red: ctrl.colorSelected == ctrl.bgColorRed, pink: ctrl.colorSelected == ctrl.bgColorPink, orange: ctrl.colorSelected == ctrl.bgColorOrange, yellow: ctrl.colorSelected == ctrl.bgColorYellow}">
      Tumblr hammock authentic, humblebrag pitchfork ramps listicle cliche distillery ethical 8-bit vice. 3 wolf moon whatever direct trade fanny pack franzen, swag polaroid austin letterpress. Street art health goth everyday carry heirloom hoodie echo park
      gluten-free irony, viral venmo brunch vegan pop-up. Man braid listicle food truck, fashion axe austin polaroid pop-up shoreditch post-ironic scenester jean shorts synth.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: hi if you find it helpful please accept my solution :)

Comment: yes! super helpful. I ended up using an array since I had to add multiple styles upon click of input button, and then assigning the corresponding index in ng-class. But your solution really put me in the right direction. thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Can you edit my answer and accept it as correct answer so that it may help other people having similar problem

Comment: Unfortunately everytime I try to edit the code it gives me an error that it is not properly formatted (not indented enough) but even when I do indent, it doesn't work. I'm sorry, don't know how else to "accept" your answer as the correct one. I appreciate your effort though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Zhiliang has the right idea.  Another solution would be to use a function call to set the background color rather than to put an inline conditional to each div, if I'm understanding your question correctly.

Also, by using an array of colors you can just add a new color in the array, add your color class and the view automatically reflects this.  You could go another step forward and store your colors in a JSON file for the controller to fetch and just update your JSON file when you want to add a new color.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oyt1jzjw/

```
function ColorsCtrl() {
  var self = this;
  self.colors = ['Red', 'Green', 'Pink'];
  self.changeColor = changeColor;

  function changeColor(color) {
    self.colorSelected = color;
  }
 }

<div ng-repeat="color in ctrl.colors">
  <input type="radio" name="color" ng-click="ctrl.changeColor(color)">{{color}}
</div>

<hr>

<div ng-class="ctrl.colorSelected">
  Stuff Here
</div>

<div ng-class="ctrl.colorSelected">
  Stuff Here
</div>
```

If you want to start changing the background color of the page, I would suggest using a directive to manipulate the dom rather than trying this in the controller.

Comment: hey thanks this was super helpful too. I'll look more into the function. very efficient. I am still very much a beginner so haven't even got to functions yet! But thanks for the great solution.